# Home hot-water radiator, high-heat paint vs not, water-based primer for oil paint

Tags: radiator, repainting, primer, oil-based-paint

Two-part question:
I have a home radiator that I have cleaned up to repaint. I was unsure if I can use regular enamel paints or is High-Heat required? I have seen answers both ways on this. The biggest factor I believe is that it is only pushing hot-water, and not steam, so temp ranges from 120 to 140 degrees.

Second. As a topcoat [1 gal. High Performance Protective Enamel Gloss Safety Red Oil-Based Interior/Exterior Paint](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Professional-1-gal-High-Performance-Protective-Enamel-Gloss-Safety-Red-Oil-Based-Interior-Exterior-Paint-7564402/100133157?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&mtc=Shopping-B-F_D24-G-D24-024_003_SPRAY_PAINT-Multi-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-FY21_SprayPaint_LIA&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D24-G-D24-024_003_SPRAY_PAINT-Multi-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-FY21_SprayPaint_LIA-71700000075826946-58700006496586419-92700058691145277&gclid=Cj0KCQjws4aKBhDPARIsAIWH0JXnm757F34ytJ_JBCpirr-iNlkn_hLJOIodNF4tqZwh_PVfHJo7SPMaAjb4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds), for this oil based paint is water-based primer fine or is it a must to use an oil based primer? At home-depot, with an employee who has worked in the painting department for years said this would be fine [Bulls Eye 1-2-3 1 qt. White Water-Based Interior/Exterior Primer and Sealer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zinsser-Bulls-Eye-1-2-3-1-qt-White-Water-Based-Interior-Exterior-Primer-and-Sealer-2004/100398398). Yet after applying it, I have read water-based primer shouldn't be used with oil paints. Is this the case?
As it now looks like this, orangish marks and spots that have thinned out. [image]

Comment: You really have 3 different questions in here and they should be asked separately. The only relation between them is that they all apply to the same radiator.

Comment: I use the Bullseye paint on steel lawn furniture , performance has been excellent. Surface prep is not very good ( no sandblast) and I leave it as the white topcoat.

Comment: It's unclear whether you know that the radiator steam or forced water.  A force water system will have two pipes connected.  If there's only one pipe connected, it's steam powered.

Comment: To get the best heat transfer paint it a black.

Comment: @JimmyJames it is hot water, no steam, it has a pipe on both ends